# Prevent user from mounting USB Key

Tags: mount, users, usb-drive

How to prevent users from mounting a USB Key which is mounted automatically on boot with with line on `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/64A5-F009 /media/usb-Samsung auto uid=1000,nodev,umask=000,nofail 0 0
```

When the computer comes out of sleep, the USB key is mounted on the adam user's media on `/media/adam/Samsung USB` instead of being mounted on `/media/usb-Samsung` as specified on `fstab` file.

**EDIT:**

I tried to put my computer on sleep mode and comes out of it and the USB Key was well mounted.
But I don't why, it's now on `/media/adam/Samsung USB`. I don't know what I did to get that!

```
mount
/dev/sdd1 on /media/adam/Samsung USB type exfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
```

I have nothing about `/dev/sdd1` about this USB Key on the fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>  <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
#PARTUUID=239a4a6c-1df0-454a-8209-2c4a54507954  /boot/efi  vfat  umask=0077  0  0
UUID=744abeb0-edab-4c77-b799-1a01578ce0df  /  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/90A4A396A4A37CFA /mnt/windows10 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
#/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
UUID=AA6C-EE7A  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
/dev/disk/by-uuid/64A5-F009 /media/usb-Samsung auto uid=1000,nodev,umask=000,nofail 0 0
```

So, I don't know what to check to prevent this behavior!

And on my Gnome file system I have 2 times this USB key:

[image]

**EDIT2**

I booted under Windows and I noticed that this key disconnected itself and then reappeared when I opened the explorer.

I thought it was a hardware problem but there is an option in Windows that automatically disables USB flash drives that are not in use to save energy:

I applied this Windows tutorial and since then no more disconnection (in french)
https://forums.commentcamarche.net/forum/affich-4544193-usb-se-deconnecte-et-se-reconnecte

So I think that my problem with Ubuntu comes from the same problem: automatic disconnection following an inactivity of the key. How can I fix this problem?

For the moment I simply put in the crontab:

```
#USB NO Disconnect
*/5 * * * * ls > /media/usb-Samsung/nodisconnect.txt
```

Every 5 minutes, I write in a file on the USB key the result of the command ls ...

This crontab solution works but it's flawed!

Comment: Strange, I would not expect this to happen. After waking up, is the drive also still mounted on the point defined in fstab (in other words, does it get mounted twice?)

Comment: Actually, yes I could not reproduce this. I have put my computer on sleep mode and comes out from it, the USB key was well mounted. I don't why I founded it this morning mounted on `/media/adam/Samsung USB` and my links on the USB key broken !

Comment: It blew up again! Currently I have the USB key mounted on: 
`/dev/sdd1 on /media/adam/Samsung USB type exfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)` I don't know why and I don't want to do to prevent it.

Comment: It could be a setting in your file manager, many filemanagers provide a feature to automount removable drives.

Comment: @mook765 Yes I think so but which option and where to modify it. I use Gnome.